# Hibernate and Sleep shutdown the PC instead of Hibernating and Sleeping - I lose my session and programs

Tags: windows, sleep, shutdown, hibernate

For some reason my HP desktop computer whenever it hibernates or sleeps, it is like it shuts down, I lose all my open programs... it is very annoying. Some say I should update the display drivers, mine are already up-to-date.

My machine is HP Z-420 running Windows 8.1 Enterprise.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have all chipset drivers installs sounds like your computer is crashing as it attempts to go into these power states which is a driver problem

Comment: Standard question: Do you have an energy saving standby killing device installed at the plug? One of those that cuts power if the power draw is less than 0.5 W?

Comment: @Peter no I don't have any of those.

Comment: @Ramhound can you provide more information on how to get this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are the buttons mapped to the appropriate functions?

ControlPanel>System>Power>Change What Power Buttons Do > Hibernate button: "$Action" sleep button: "$Action" etc.

Example on Win7 laptop. I know that it is nether win 8 nor a desktop with hibernate and sleep buttons but the principle is the same.

[image]

Comment: I don't see Device under control panel. You mean devices and printers?

Comment: Sounds about right. Different operating systems, different skins, different terms. Whichever makes the most sense.

Comment: But I don't see any Lid and Buttons ...etc I am on Windows btw

Comment: Corrected original post. See above, and sorry for misleading you.

Comment: OK I see. so it is a Desktop I should've mentioned and these are correct. power button --> shutdown, and the sleep --> sleep. It might be a driver issue.

Comment: Are the hibernate buttons on a keyboard, or are they built in? If 2, did you build the computer, or someone else?

Comment: hibernate button in UI - no actual hardware button. It is the company machine new HP. I know the IT department does not allow me to change power plan to Never Sleep which solves the issue for me. I thought I might find a quick fix online before I go through process of contacting IT.

Comment: thanks I dealt with it with the IT department at work... I got out of the electric plan enforcement.